# Python Variable Invalid Syntax

Tags: python

```
import pywapi
import string
zip = input(" ZIP Code: ")
cs = input("City, State: ")

weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('zip')

print "Weather.com says: It is " + .lower(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text']) + " and " + weather_com_result['current_conditions'] + ['temperature'] + "F now in" ['cs'] + "./n/n"
```

It gives me an error with 'cs'. Anyone know why?

Comment: Sailormanenzo: There is no need to leave thanks in the question.  If there is an answer which best helped you to a solution, indicate it by ticking the large checkmark next to it on the left.

Comment: Oh yes I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your print statement like below (I mean the format) instead of using string concat operation. I would not say its not correct to write that way but the below way is always a better operation since you will have the control on string type as well.

```
import pywapi
import string
zip = input(" ZIP Code: ")
cs = raw_input("City, State: ")

weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('zip')

print "Weather.com says: It is %s and %s F now in %s \n \n." %(str(lower(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text'])), str(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['temperature']), str(cs))
```

However if you still need it in the concat way use the below sample syntax.

```
import pywapi
import string
zip = input(" ZIP Code: ")
cs = raw_input("City, State: ")

weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('zip')
print "Weather.com says: It is ." + str.lower('abc') + " and " + 'def' + 'ghi' + "F now in " + str('ijk') + ".\n\n"
```

Errors in your program

Your print statement has a variable

> weather_com_result['current_conditions'] + ['temperature'] it should be weather_com_result['current_conditions']['temperature']

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: When I use the first option I get:       `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather1.py", line 5, in <module>
    cs = input("City, State: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'NYC' is not defined
`

Comment: Also on the second option

Comment: Try using raw_input instead of input. Let me know if you are still having issues, Looks like pywapi is something custom that you have written. So I did not test the whole stuff. Just looked at the traceback.

Comment: Yes pywapi is a program made by someone from GitHub

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather.py", line 8, in <module>
    print "Weather.com says: It is %s and %s F now in %s \n \n." %(str(lower(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text'])), str(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['temperature']), str(cs))
NameError: name 'lower' is not defined
`

Comment: @Sailormanenzo str(lower(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text']‌​)) is not correct instead it should be str. lower(weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text']‌​)). (str.lower) is the function

Answer (score 2):

You must replace `['cs']` with `+ cs`.

For the formatting, you can use the `%` syntax. Then, you will not have errors like this.